# GStreamer change image size dynamically

Tags: python, gstreamer

First of all: yes I know this has been asked before but the answer doesnt really help me as I am not that familiar with Gstreamer yet and I need some more help. I'm trying to make a pipeline with `videocrop` and change the values dynamically. The following is my code which returns the error: `TypeError: object of type GstVideoCrop does not have property caps`. So I guess it's either not possible or I'm doing it the wrong way... Thank you for your help!

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Tcam', '0.1')
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, Tcam

GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(())
p = Gst.parse_launch("tcambin name=src ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx ! videocrop name=try top=0 left=300 right=150 bottom=0 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink")
p.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
p.set_state(Gst.State.READY)
m = p.get_by_name("try")
caps = Gst.caps_from_string("videocrop name=try top=500 left=300 right=150 bottom=0")
m.set_property("caps", caps)
p.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
GObject.MainLoop.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got it working! I was trying it the wrong way. The following works:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Tcam', '0.1')
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, Tcam

GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(())
p = Gst.parse_launch("tcambin name=src ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx ! videocrop name=caps top=0 left=300 right=150 bottom=0 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink")
p.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
p.set_state(Gst.State.READY)
m = p.get_by_name("caps")

m.set_property("top", 500)
p.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
GObject.MainLoop.run()
```